# How to check what class calls 'Runtime' in Java?

Tags: java

I'm submitting a solution to Topcoder. I keep getting the error,
`Compilation failed because there is no need to make use of 'Runtime' anywhere in your code, for security purposes.`

I don't use `Runtime` class, no reflections and no obj.getClass.

What could be possibly causing this?

Comment: Found a similar issue on the [TopCoder forums](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=37B6A8137A267BFB638A19AD423CAE90?module=Thread&threadID=846308&start=0&mc=2#1980933) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

From [this link on the TopCoder Forum](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=37B6A8137A267BFB638A19AD423CAE90?module=Thread&threadID=846308&start=0&mc=2#1980933), I am led to believe this is the resolution:

> reference to @SafeVarargs which doesn't have the text 'Runtime' and belongs to java.lang but counted as invalid with a misleading message.

Comment: I wish it could be that simple. It seems like there is a class that implicitly imported Runtime and it's quite difficult to get since I have around 15K of code lines ....